# Is the builtin hash method of Python2.6 stable across architectures?

Tags: python

I need to compute a hash that needs to be stable across architectures. Is python's hash() stable?

To be more specific, the example below shows hash() computing the same value on two different hosts/architectures:

```
# on OSX based laptop
>>> hash((1,2,3,4))
485696759010151909
# on x86_64 Linux host
>>> hash((1,2,3,4))
485696759010151909
```

The above is true for at least those inputs, but my question is for the general case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need a well defined hash, you can use one out of [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib).

Comment: For this, you need a stable `str`, which I believe is true.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, the results of `str()` should be the same across platforms and implementations.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just as straightforward too. Thanks

Comment: The result of `str()` is not stable for some objects types. For example, any instance of a user-defined class that contains its memory address in `str(obj)` (the default for most user-defined types).

Answer (score 9):

The `hash()` function is not what you want; finding a reliable way to serialize the object (eg `str()` or `repr()`) and running it through `hashlib.md5()` would probably be much more preferrable.

In detail - `hash()` is designed to return an integer which uniquely identifies an object *only within it's lifetime*. Once the program is run again, constructing a new object may in fact have a different hash. Destroying an object means there's a chance another object will have that hash in the future. See python's definition of [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable) for more.

Behind the scenes, most user-defined python objects fall back to [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) to provide their hash value. While you're not supposed to make use of this, `id(obj)` and thus `hash(obj)` is usually implemented (eg in CPython) as the memory address of the underlying Python object. Thus you can see why it can't be relied on for anything.

The behavior you currently see is only reliable for certain builtin python objects, and that not very far. `hash({})` for instance is not possible.

---

Regarding `hashlib.md5(str(obj))` or equivalent - you'll need to make sure `str(obj)` is reliably the same. In particular, if you have a dictionary being rendering within that string, it may not list it's keys in the same order. There may also be subtle differences between python versions... I would definitely recommend unittests for any implementation you rely on.

Comment: The second paragraph could really use a reference. Is there an official documentation of that information?

Comment: @phihag Pretty much all the 2nd & 3rd paragraphs are just a restatement of the info in the official `hashable` and `id()` documentation linked to within the paragraphs; though the official docs could spell things out a little better.

Comment: It does not identify an object uniquely. It only provides a mapping into the int domain with a good distribution. Collisions are unavoidable and cared for.

Answer (score 6):

No.

```
x86_64
>>> print hash("a")
12416037344

i386
>>> print hash("a")
-468864544
```

If you need a stable hash, create a digest of your data using something like sha1, which can be found in [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)

Answer (score 5):

No. On ARM with python 2.6:

```
>>> hash((1,2,3,4))
```

`89902565`